# Excel Vba: limit on maximum number of data points across all charts?

Tags: excel, charts, vba

I writing code to produce about 7 charts in Excel Vba. There are many data points involved. I can produce about 5 charts until I get the error **Run-time error 1004: The maximum number of data series per chart is 255**.

This error occurs at the line

```
Set mychart = Activeworkbook.Charts.Add
```

This is interesting because I do not have any charts with more than 3 data series. Further, like I said, I can make any combination of charts that is less than the total. 
It seems like there's a limit on the number of total data points being used across all charts.

Thanks.

Comment: If your code is as simple as that, there shouldn't be any problem. You are not assigning it any series or value by just that so no reason to receive such error. Are you sure that that like is causing the error? Is it somewhere within a loop or *With Statement* somehow?

Comment: execution stops at this line and produces the forementioned error. it is not in a loop or with statement, just a standalone line. it's puzzling.

Comment: Yeah, I'm puzzled as well. I run that same line 100x and I did not produce the error.

Comment: but are you creating charts with large datasets?

Comment: Read my 1st comment. What is the line of code before that line?

Comment: there is a main module that calls several class modules which make charts. in each class module the first things to happen are variable declarations and class initialization. next i add a chart to the workbook using charts.add. this is where the error comes. to restate, the error comes when i try to add a new chart during the fifth or so call to one of my class modules

Comment: i can post the actual code tomorrow

Comment: When the chart is created, is the active cell within a huge block of data? Excel tries to populate the inserted chart with the range that contains the active cell.

Comment: @Jon Peltier. Sorry for the late response. Yes, the active cell is within a worksheet that is full of data... This is a bug then. Thanks

Comment: No, it is not a bug. It is intentional and well-documented behavior. You need to change the active cell, make your chart, and change back. See the code sample in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like

```
Dim rngActive As Range
Dim rngSelect As Range

Set rngActive = activecell
set rngSelect = selection

activesheet.cells(1,1).Offset(activesheet.usedrange.rows.count+1).select

' do your chart here

rngSelect.Select
rngActive.Activate
```